# How to get row count inside Gridview label

Tags: asp.net, gridview, label, rowcount

I have an ItemTemplate Label inside Gridview which I haven't bound with any DataField.
I have userId as one of the columns of GridView.
Based on the userId column, I want to get total no of assets acquired by the User. The totalNo doesn't exists in the database. I have to manually fire a query and get total no of row counts.

Now, how to put this rowCount for each user inside GridView?

Any ideas?
I have tried onRowDataBound and FindControl, but how do I get rowIndex for that particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add an event function for the DataBound on your GridView and when its render the Header you can change it like:

```
protected void grdView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "Custom header";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code and all the cells got "Custom Header" text.
So I changed DataControlRowType.Header to DataControlRowType.DataRow.

Now, for 2nd column, in all cells, I am getting same value.

Below is my code,

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();;
                }
            }

What I actually need is different values for each row based on the UserId in the first column of the GridView.